# Get image from google maps iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I get image from google maps iframe? Thanks.
For example I have next iframe:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com.ua/maps?q=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2,+%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&amp;gl=ua&amp;t=h&amp;z=10&amp;ll=46.975033,31.994583&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

And I need tage an image of this map. It`s really?

Comment: Take a look at the static map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: browser security issue . your not allowed

Comment: Isn't it against TOS?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have access to the content of an iframe of different domain. See [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe).